# Need help/suggestion for developing publisher subscription model.

Tags: c#-4.0, design-patterns

I have n number of clients(say a typical browser) connected to a server if any client publishes a message all other clients should be able to view it I.E Read/Reply the message.So any client can be a publisher as well as subscriber.After doing a bit of investigation i found out **OBSERVER** design pattern can be one probable solution(might be wrong).Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Maybe you could use [SignalR](http://signalr.net/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an out-of-the-box solution for that. It will save you a lot of work and problems such as scalability, security, etc.. And, trust me, that's quite a lot to tackle.

I work for Realtime.co and we do exactly that. Check out the examples here: https://github.com/RTWWorld/pubsub-examples/tree/master/Javascript

You can get a free account at http://www.realtime.co.

We use the pub/sub pattern in which you can subscribe or publish to channels. Whoever is subscribing a channel will receive the data being published there.

Here's a piece of code as an example:

```
<input type="text" id="mensagem" />
<input type="button" onclick="sendMessage();" value="Send" />
<div id="log"></div>

<script src="http://code.xrtml.org/xrtml-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script>
    var appkey = 'YOUR_APP_KEY';
    var url = 'http://ortc-developers.realtime.co/server/2.1';
    var shoutbox;

    xRTML.load(function(){

        xRTML.Config.debug = true;

        xRTML.ConnectionManager.create(
        {
            id: 'myConn',
            appkey: appkey,
            authToken: 'anything',
            url: url,
            channels: [
                {name: 'user:channel_2'},
                {name: 'user:channel_1'}
            ]
        }).bind(
        {
            message: function(e) {
                var log = document.getElementById('log');
                log.innerHTML = log.innerHTML + '<br />' + e.message;
            }
        });

    });

    function sendMessage(){
        var msg = document.getElementById('mensagem').value;

        xRTML.ConnectionManager.sendMessage({
            connections: ['myConn'],
            channel: 'user:channel_2',
            content: msg
        });
    }

</script>
```

When you click the "Send" button you will publish a message to channel "user:channel_2". Since our code is subscribing to both "user:channel_1" and "user:channel_2", you will also receive the message. If you open this example on several browsers, all of them will get the message.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i will surely look into it.